# Calculate number of time streak of categories change in a row in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
Row number   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1                1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
2                    1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
3                1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
```

I am trying to calculate the number of times the number changes between 1 and 0 excluding the Nulls

The result I am expecting is this

```
Row Number    No of changes
----------    --------------
1                4
2                4
3                4
```

An explanation for row 1

In row 1, A has a null so we exclude that.

B and C have 1 which is our first set of values.

D and E have 0 which is our second set of values. Now **Change** = 1

F has our third set of values which is 1. Now **Change** = 1+1

G and H have 0 which is our third set of values. Now **Change** = 1+1+1

I and J have 1 which is our fourth set of values. Now **Change** = 1+1+1+1 =4

Comment: What solutions have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried using this
table1 <- test[,-c(1)] %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(col,val,-rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(grp_num = cumsum(val != lag(val, default = -99))) %>%
  group_by(rowname,val,grp_num) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(num = n(),
                   range = paste0(first(col), "-", last(col)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach.
I gather into longer format (from `tidyr::pivot_longer`), then add a helper column noting when we have a change from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0, and then sum those by row.

```
library(tidyverse)            
df %>%
  # before tidyr 1.0, this would be   gather(col, value, -1)
  pivot_longer(-1, "col") %>%
  group_by(Row.number) %>%
  mutate(chg = value == 1 & lag(value) == 0 |
           value == 0 & lag(value) == 1) %>%
  summarize(no_chgs = sum(chg, na.rm = T))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Row.number no_chgs
       <int>   <int>
1          1       4
2          2       4
3          3       4
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "'Row number'   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
            1            NA  1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
            2            NA  NA  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
            3            NA  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1")
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way I can use gather instead of pivot_longer? I somehow cannot install the new tidyverse

Comment: Edited to add alternative:  `tidyr::gather(col, value, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[,
   no_change := max(rleid(na.omit(t(.SD)))) - 1,
   by = RowNumber
   ]
dt
```

Alternatively, here's a base version:

```
apply(df[, -1],
      1,
      function(x) {
        complete_case = complete.cases(x)
        if (sum(complete_case) > 0) {
          return(length(rle(x[complete_case])$lengths) - 1)
        } else {
          return (0)
        }
        }
      )
```